# How to delete empty key in from document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a document in db as

{
name:"Rajeev",
"":"",
lastname:"Ranjan"
}

and i want to delete "":"" from this document so that document would be like 
{
name:"Rajeev",
lastname:"Ranjan"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with a script in command line (for instance) :

```
db.{collection}.find({"name":"Rajeev"}).forEach(function(document) {
    delete document[''];
    db.{collection}.save(document);
});
```